# Pillow: strange behavior using Draw.rectangle

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am drawing rectangles in a for-loop using Pillow. This worked on my desktop computer, but throwing a strange exception on my laptop.

This is the code (shortened):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
(...)
img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
rimg = img.copy()
rimg_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rimg)
(...)
(for-loop)
    rimg_draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=None, outline=(255, 0, 0))
```

This throws the following exception:

```
rimg_draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=None, outline=(255, 0, 0))
  File "/home/daniel/tensorflow2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 203, in rectangle
    ink, fill = self._getink(outline, fill)
  File "/home/daniel/tensorflow2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 124, in _getink
    ink = self.draw.draw_ink(ink, self.mode)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

I do not understand, why this code fails: at Pillow's very own [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#methods) `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle` is defined **with** these arguments: `rectangle(xy, fill=None, outline=None)`.

Since the documentation explicitly lists the optional parameters `fill` and `outline`, why is Pillow complaining that it only takes 1 argument?

`pip freeze` says Pillows version is `3.3.1`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you read a *grayscale* image and try to draw a *color* rectangle on it, you'll get the error message: `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`

You need to give a color like `outline=(255)`, not a RGB color like `outline=(255, 0, 0)`. Otherwise you get the error because you're giving 3 color arguments, not one. If you do want to draw color onto a grayscale image, you can convert the image to RGB first: `img = img.convert('RGB')`

Edit: since many other people hit this problem too, I filed a bug against Pillow and they promptly [made a fix](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/5504). So this question and answer will hopefully soon be obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

After slight adjustments to your code to make it run, I was not able to reproduce the exception.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.open('testfig.png')
rimg = img.copy()
rimg_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rimg)
rimg_draw.rectangle((10, 10, 30, 30), fill=None, outline=(255, 0, 0))
rimg.show()
```

However, I'm running Python 3.4.4 and Pillow 3.2.0 on my system. Is there any obvious difference in versions on your laptop compared to your desktop?

Can you have a deeper look at your code lines 124 and 203, respectively, or provide us with a working code snippet that creates this exception for you?

Comment: No. I am using Python 2.7 on both, including Pillow 3.3.1 in a virtual env. Even the OS is the same (Manjaro, Arch-Fork). However, I was able to "fix" the exception: I've just completely removed Pillow + depedencies and reinstalled it...which is very strange, since the Python exception was indicating that really something with the usage of the method was wrong...